# Selecting OpAmps for Transimpedence Application

Tags: operational-amplifier, transimpedance

Hi I am working on an application that will use a PIN diode to detect very small light intensity changes. Looking for low noise, single 5V rail operation, and high gain. Cost is a secondary consideration. All other metrics such as bandwidth, slew rate are not as important. I am trying to decide how to build my circuit but could use some advice - I realize there is no one answer in analog design but some advice would help me move beyond the simple circuits we were taught in school.

1) How do you select the first stage for a transimpedence amplifier such as this? I have found several parts that seem to match the application well but I am not sure how I should chose between them.

http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/62689f.pdf 
http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/624012fe.pdf
http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/624678fa.pdf

2) Is it better to build a CMOS buffer 1st stage with a discrete CMOS like so? Or just feed it straight into one of the other Op-Amps?

[image]

3) If my currents will be on the order of pA the how do I chose subsequent stages for the amplifier? Should I use the same amplifier again, just anything that will give me the right gain or are there other gotchas I need to anticipate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found [this](http://www.analog.com/designtools/en/photodiode/#/photoDiode) (below) useful. It's a site offered by Analog Devices and appears to give useful information on the design of TIAs for photodiodes: -

[image]

The wizard produces several output specifications such as ENOB, SNR, pulse response, bode plot, spectral noise etc.. All good stuff. It also recommends the best/most suitable op-amp. I think it's a good start to any design and allows you to play around with values.

If you are not using high capacitance photodiodes and speed isn't that important the JFET amplifier (bootstrap circuit) is probably not needed in your design.